# How to identify combination of number and character in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a requirement where I have to find number of records in a special pattern in the field ref_id in a table. It's a varchar column. I need to find all the records where 8th, 9th and 10th character are numeric+XX. That is it should be like 2XX or 8XX. I tried using regexp :digit: but no luck. Essentially I am looking for all records where 8th-10th characters are 1XX, 2XX, 3XX… etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using REGEXP_LIKE, replace `table` with Yours:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ref_id,'^.{7}[0-9]XX');
```

`.{7}` whatever seven characters

`[0-9]` 8th character digit

`XX` 9th and 10th characters X

Or with `[:digit:]` class as You are mentioning, You may use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ref_id,'^.{7}[[:digit:]]XX');
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved using standard non-regex SQL functions

```
select * from t where s like '________XX%'     -- any 8 characters and then XX
      AND translate( substr(s,8,1),'?0123456789','?') is  null; --8th one is numeric
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8dea53c71169933d5b2d8b96421ad7ea)

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regexp:

```
select * from mytable where substr(ref_id, 8, 3) in ('0XX','1XX','2XX','3XX','4XX','5XX','6XX','7XX','8XX','9XX')
```

or

```
select * from mytable where substr(ref_id, 8, 3) in ('1XX','2XX','3XX','4XX','5XX','6XX','7XX','8XX','9XX')
```

I don't know if '0XX' is a valid match or not.

Regexp's tend to be slow.